# Ruby on Rails server started but can't connect to http://localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and helping on an existing project. I ran rails server, and received the following output

```
=> Booting Unicorn
=> Rails 4.2.5.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
I, [2016-12-05T13:44:05.166061 #15228]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=11
I, [2016-12-05T13:44:05.185700 #15228]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2016-12-05T13:44:05.187404 #15242]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2016-12-05T13:44:05.187827 #15243]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2016-12-05T13:44:05.188412 #15244]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
^CI, [2016-12-05T13:45:11.233928 #15228]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15244 exit 0> worker=2
I, [2016-12-05T13:45:11.234060 #15228]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15243 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2016-12-05T13:45:11.234227 #15228]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15242 exit 0> worker=0
```

Which seems to indicate that the server is up and running. However, I am unable to connect to http://localhost:3000, it gives me an error connection refused. Does anybody know how I can go about debugging this?

Comment: paste the error msg plz

Comment: Rails version 4.2.5.2

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: Error message: This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Did you mean http://localhost3000.org/?
Search Google for localhost 3000
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Does it reference your database in the error?  Something like ERRNO:::CONNECTION REfused and then pg or sqlite perhaps?

Comment: No, there's no mention of the database, the two lines I pasted above were the full output in my browser

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get the same error when trying to connect from other browsers?

Comment: try    rails s 0.0.0.0

Comment: I tried both firefox and chrome

Comment: I tried rails s -b 0.0.0.0, no luck

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a firewall/antivirus suite or some configuration in your browser that would be blocking access to localhost ?

Can you try to `curl localhost:3000` if you're under Linux ?

Comment: I get curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused

Answer (score 1):

With rails 4.2.0, the server binds to localhost by default, instead of 0.0.0.0. When working with a rails in a virtual box, accessing the server from the host computer, the binding address needs to be 0.0.0.0

Start rails server with -b0.0.0.0 to make the rails server accessible from the host computer/browser.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#default-host-for-rails-server https://github.com/samuelkadolph/unicorn-rails/issues/12#issuecomment-60875268

or try passing different port

```
rails s -p 3001
```

Comment: I actually tried both rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001 as well, but it yielded the same results.

Comment: send me your teamViewer CRED if you have no issue :)

Comment: Okay I downloaded teamviewer, I just give you the ID and password?

Comment: I had this problem while running rails in docker.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your hosts file.

Linux `/etc/hosts`

Windows `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

and editing the localhosts to serve 127.0.0.1. or move it so it is last. Rails will take the last mention of localhost and use it.

Or you can go even deper and try using `telnet localhost 3000` to tell if the port is unavailable at the TCP level.

My hosts file looks something like

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       myPC

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

Comment: ##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

that's my localhost file.

Comment: 127.0.0.1       localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

This is mine and everything is peachy.